# Add value to string if string doesn't already contain this value

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, addition

I need to add value to string without making `"TRC+TRC"` cells.
So if it already contains TRC -> add nothing.
How to do it?

```py
for i in range(len(df)):
  d = str(df['description'][i]).lower()
  if df['segment'][i] == 'shopping':
    if any(TRC in d for TRC in TRC):
      if (df['landsize'][i] > 9000):
        df['class'][i] = (f"{df['class'][i]} + TRC")
        continue
```

and what are other variants to do this thing?

```py
df['class'][i] = (f"{df['class'][i]} + TRC")
```

Comment: Can TRC be in the middle of the string or will it always be at the start or end?

Comment: i have multiple classes like TRC, so it may add multiple times and in random positions, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for, definitely avoid loops in pandas in anyway possible.
Hope that this is what you meant :)

```
df['description'] = df['description'].str.lower()

df.loc[(df['segment'] == 'shopping')
   &(~df['description'].str.contains('trc')) 
   & (df['landsize'] > 9000)
   , 'class'] += "TRC"
```

Comment: i have both variants of code: with loops and with loc. But @Benoit Drogou wrote with iloc for some reason :)
but with loc i have another troubles, so i'm trying to do this as loop now

Comment: what does ```~``` mean?

Comment: Maybe try to solve your loc problem? 
It's the cleaner way to approach it in my opinion,

Comment: ~ means not, so it checks that description doesn't contain trc

Answer (score 1):

Loops are not pythonic at all, the more you are avoiding them the better, faster and more efficient your code is.

```py
df.loc[ (df['segment']=='shopping')
       & (df['landsize']>9000)
       & (~df['class'].str.contains(pat='TRC', na=False))
       , 'class'] += 'TRC'
```

I maybe misunderstood your issue

Comment: I think they meant that `df['class']` cells must be appended 'TRC' under the conditions, not _make_ it 'TRC'.

Comment: sure, then += works for dataframe as well, I updated the answer